# How to prevent sorting when merging array like objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

When merging array like objects using lodash, the result will be sorted according to the indices. How to prevent such sorting?

For an example, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmehri/jh330qbk/2/):

```
const response1 = { nested: { obj: { 'b': 2 } }};
const response2 = { nested: { obj: { 'a': 2 } }};

const merge1 = _.merge({}, response1, response2);
console.log(merge1); // { nested: { obj: { b: 2, a: 2 } } }


const response3 = { nested: { obj: { 2: 2 } }};
const response4 = { nested: { obj: { 1: 1 } }};

const merge2 = _.merge({}, response3, response4);
console.log(merge2); // { nested: { obj: { '1': 1, '2': 2 } } }
```

Comment: You could maybe just `Object.assign()` the specific `obj` layer if it's only `x.nested.obj` that differs https://jsfiddle.net/98ue1kfa/13/

Comment: The shapes of objects are not known from the beginning and I don't want to make assumptions regarding that. In addition, in your jsfiddle the problem is still not resolved, the merge is still sorted, `{ nested: { obj: { '1': 1, '2': 2 } } }.`